# create document from html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to create the document object from html string retrieved using a ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: mylist.url,    //url to a webpage
    cache: false,
}).done(function(webpage) {
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(webpage) //this doesn't work
});
```

Comment: `createHMTLDocument(//this is for title element)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument

Comment: isn't here one for the whole?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createDocument

Comment: no that doesn't do the work. 'webpage' is a string object containing the sourcecode of the whole page (url). I need to create a document object from that string.

Comment: What do you return to ajax request? what is the content and dataType of "webpage"? try **console.log(webpage);** after var doc=...;

Comment: if you return an html string you can do **$(document).html(webpage);**

Comment: as an alternative use `$.parseHTML(value.value)`